# Can Rotation gesture on a subview of a ScrollView and its pinch zoom work hand in hand?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIScrollView containing a UIImageView.
now I also added a two finger rotation gesture  to the imageView.

now the Rotation is not being recognized and whatever I do , it only pinch zooms the image.

I am not sure that Can I test a rotation gesture on simulator with option key and mouse ?

and If yes then is it that that my touches are all going to ScrollView instead of the gestureRecognizer added to the imageView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your scrollview swallows all your touches. You have to transfer the touches from scrollview to your subview. You can check that in the below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8831018/641062